# 2 more weeks than usual? or 2 weeks more than usual?

Tags: grammar

Context is as below.
ABC company realized transit time currently takes 2 weeks compared to the usual time.
So they need to inform their customers that it will take them 2 weeks to receive the goods.
In that case, can I say something as follows?

Dear Customers,

> (1) It will take approximately 2 more weeks than usual.

> (2) It will take approximately 2 weeks more than usual.

.===================================================================.

PS: As far as I know, native speakers say things like this.

For example,

aa) You should go to 2 more bus stops to get the library. --> Word order: [2 + more + bus stops]

bb) We have sold more than 2,000 toys. --> Word order: [more than + 2,000 + toys]

However I have no idea of a correct way about fused contents like my question.

Comment: I can only tell from what sounds more natural to my ear. In this case: It will take approximately 2 weeks more than usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not edited your question because to do so would be to answer it without explanation.

The answer hinges on the use of *more*. *More* is a comparative and requires the comparison of two things. One is more than the other.

The first sentence of your question states that the time is two weeks compared to the normal time. You do not state the normal time; it may be bigger or smaller. The comparison is meaningless. The second sentence says the time is two weeks.

You then give sentences that use *more* to tell us that the time is greater than normal by two weeks. This clarifies the intention of your original but because you told us the time is two weeks, you are saying normal time is zero. This is unlikely!

Your first paragraph should therefore be corrected to read

“ABC company realized transit time currently takes 2 weeks **more than** the usual time. So they need to inform their customers that it will take them 2 **more** weeks to receive the goods.”

You could also use “... 2 weeks **more** to receive...”. As a native speaker, I am accustomed to both constructions. Either of your suggestions is acceptable.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much.
Now I would like to be clear of usages of "more" and "than".

Comment: First of all, in my paragraph explaining context, <ABC company realized transit time currently takes 2 weeks compared to the usual time.> It is not clear. Right? I should have said the usual time, for eaxmple, 1 week or something.

Comment: Therefore could you check, the following sentences are possible or not?

(1) It will take approximately 2 more weeks than usual.

(2) It will take approximately 2 weeks more than usual.

Comment: You have understood correctly.

Comment: I am sorry to keep you asked, So I want to know (1) and (2) are possible.

Comment: Yes both (1) and (2) are possible and usable. I slightly prefer (2)  because it sounds more familiar to me but there is no significant difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to say 'two weeks *longer* than usual'. We can speak of 'two more weeks' in some contexts (*I have two more weeks of holiday*), but it doesn't sound natural here.